pd.concat() when dataframes share a column
I am trying to concatenate two dataframes that share a column. One dataframe has all the columns, but the second one is just the single changed column. I want to concatenate them so that the old values are overwritten by the new values. I've tried every way I can think of to do this, but I'm not making any progress. Here's what I want to happen:
A B
0 1 2
1 2 3

concatenate with:
A
0 3
1 4

to be:
A B
0 3 2
1 4 3

pd.concat(frames, axis=1) has gotten me the closest. Two rows are messed up but they should be combined. The incorrect rows show like this:
  A   B
0 1   NaN
1 NaN 1

The rows should be combined together to get the correct output.

There is same number of rows in both DataFrames?

Can you provide an example dataset, and your desired output of the combined dataset?

I think concat appends the data either in the row direction or in the column direction. It will not overwrite the old values. If you want to overwrite the old values, you should use the update method in the dataframe. Here is an example:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
    'Score': [85, 90, 95, 80]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [2, 4],
    'Score': [88, 85]
})

Set the index on which you will update the values. If old values are found they will be overwritten; otherwise, a new row will be added. If You have a extra column value, that will also get added with the given value for that row. The rest will be None if ID is not found.
df1.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

now update df1 with the values from df2
df1.update(df2)

after updating, you can reset the index if required
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df1)


IIUC use DataFrame.combine_first:
out = df2.combine_first(df1)
print (out)
   A  B
0  3  2
1  4  3

For different number of rows:
print (df1)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  8  9

print (df2)
   A
0  3
1  4

out = df2.combine_first(df1)
print (out)
   A  B
0  3  2
1  4  3
2  8  9


print (df1)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3

print (df2)
   A
0  3
1  4
2  7

out = df2.combine_first(df1)
print (out)
   A    B
0  3  2.0
1  4  3.0
2  7  NaN


Another possible solution:
df.loc[df2.index, df2.columns] = df2

